# How to refresh the social pane/activities section on save in dynamics crm?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to refresh the Social Pane section through javascript in dynamics CRM every time a record gets saved. I do not want to refresh the whole form.

Comment: I think programatically clicking one of the links ("notes", "posts" etc.) of the social pane should work but I don't have any actual code to share

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way of refreshing the social pane. The only supported solution is to refresh the entire form to also have the social pane refresh.

Alternatively you can remove the social pane from the form and instead add a subgrid of e.g. activities. This subgrid can then be refreshed through JavaScript by using [Xrm.Page.getControl(subgridname).refresh()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#Anchor_16)